# Django: Error 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) when doing ajax call

Tags: python, ajax, django, jquery

Hi when I'm doing ajax call, I'm getting this in console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration/check/username/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

Also when I click on this link, I'm getting this:

```
DoesNotExist at /registration/check/username/
User matching query does not exist.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration/check/username/
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
```

JQuery:

```
function check_username() {
    $("#id_username").change(function() {
        var user = $("#id_username").val();
        var status = $("#id_username").nextAll(".status").first().empty();
        var checking = '<img src="/site_media/images/loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> Checking availability...';
        var success = '<img src="/site_media/images/tick.gif" align="absmiddle">';
        var e_length = '<p>User name have to be longer</p>';
        if (user.length >= 3) {
            status.append(checking);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/registration/check/username/",
                type: "POST",
                data: { username : $("#id_username").val() },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (msg == '1') {
                        status.append(success);
                    }
                    else {
                        status.append("This username is already in use");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else if (user.length <= 3 && user.length != 0) {
            status.append(e_length);
        }
        else {
            status;
        }
    });
}
```

Html:

```
{% block main-menu %} 
    <div class="contentarea">
            <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                <ul id="reg-form">
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
                        <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" />
                        <div class="status"></div>
                    </li>
```

Urls.py:

```
...
(r'^registration/check/([\w|\W]+)/$', register_check),
...
```

Views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def register_check(request, variable):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if variable == 'username':
            user = User.objects.get(username__exact = request.POST['username']);
            if user:
                msg = "1"
            else:
                msg = '0'
        return HttpResponse(msg)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("0")
```

Comment: Can you check in Chrome inspector what value for `username` is getting sent? At the moment, the error is being caused by the query `User.objects.get(...)` not being able to find a match suggesting that `request.POST['username']` is being received but is not in the DB

Comment: I'm trying to find over there how to check what was sent, but can't find where is it. Can you please tell me where should I look?

Comment: You don't have a csrfmiddlewaretoken value in your data dict, but you appear to be using csrf_exempt so I have no idea where the 403 is coming from. Your question is officially confusing since you're talking about multiple problems at once. a 500, a 403, and code for each.

Comment: I know, it confuses me even more :) When I add Quotes around "register_check", like @just-another-dunce sugested, i'm getting 403 forbidden error, without quotes it's 500 internal server one.

Comment: @Timmy O'Mahony I found where I can check what I sent: and It looks like I'm sending correct info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally use strings for the `urls.py`.  Instead of using

```
(r'^registration/check/([\w|\W]+)/$', register_check),
```

use

```
(r'^registration/check/([\w|\W]+)/$', "register_check"),
```

and the first should be the path to your views file.

**update**

According to Django's 1.4 website [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax), you need to add the csrf token to the request in the headers.  I didn't read the entire chunk of code though.

Comment: I added quotes to urls.py. And now I'm getting another error: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration/check/username/ 403 (FORBIDDEN). And it looks for me like I'm missing csrf_token somewhere, but I have it in form and in view, I updated my question and added html.